# SHA1 implementation for 8051 MCU?

Tags: md5, sha1, 8051

I'm looking for a space-efficient implementation of SHA1 or similar cryptographic hash for the 8051 microcontroller. C or assembly. Google searches have come up with nothing so far. Any guidance?

Comment: The ["PIC assembly code simplify"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27781/pic-assembly-code-simplify) question also seems to involve getting a cryptographic hash running on the 8051.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking for app notes or samples from other manufacturers (minding the license) and controllers (Atmel, TI, NXP, Microchip etc).